# How to Override new tab when grid row is clicked using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I Have a grid on first tab, when I click on first row , it opens new tab and first row details will be displayed , when I click on second row, already opened new tab should be overriden with second row details. How to do it using jQuery & JavaScript ?

Below is the code I am using currently and it is opening multiple new tabs instead of overriding.

```
window.open(_navUrl, '_blank','noreferrer',true);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
window.open(_navUrl, '_blank','noreferrer',true);
```

Well, your `noreferrer` value should be a **unique referer**, for example "tab1", "tab2", "tab3", ...

Then you could refer to it when opening your new window.

Answer (score 0):

The windowName [parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open) controls which window/tab is used.

> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/open
>
> A DOMString specifying the name of the browsing context (window,  or tab) into which to load the specified resource; if the name doesn't indicate an existing context, a new window is created and is given the name specified by windowName.
>
> ...
>
> To open a new window on every call of window.open(), use the special value `_blank` for windowName.

So by using `_blank` each time, you are explicitly saying: open a new window.  Instead, use the same name each time, eg

```
window.open(_navUrl, 'gridtab','noreferrer',true);
```

then it will reuse the same window/tab.

Comment: I have implemented this way , but multiple tabs are opening still.